# How to Dynamically Change Value of Formik Input Based on FieldArray Inputs

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-forms

I am working on a form with formik that has an array of fields. I want to dynamically add value in `total` and `sub total` fields based on the field array.

Here is the code

Formik Form

```
 <Formik
    initialValues={addPurchasesInitialValues}
    validationSchema={addPurchasesValidationSchema}
    onSubmit={hanldeSubmit}
  >
    {(props) => (
      <form>
        <div className=" text-gray-700 rounded w-11/12 ml-auto mr-auto ">
          <div className="mt-5  max-h-[500px] overflow-y-auto">
            <span className="text-gray-600">Items Information</span>
            <FieldArray
              name="items"
              render={(arrayHelpers) => {
                const items = props.values.items;
                return (
                  <div>
                    {!!items &&
                      items.length &&
                      items.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                          <div className="flex" key={index}>
                            <CustomInput
                              name={`items.${index}.itemName`}
                              placeholder="Item Name"
                            />
                            <CustomInput
                              name={`items.${index}.itemType`}
                              placeholder="Item Type"
                            />
                            <CustomInput
                              type="number"
                              name={`items.${index}.itemRate`}
                              placeholder="Rate"
                            />
                            <CustomInput
                              type="number"
                              name={`items.${index}.itemQuantity`}
                              placeholder="Quantity"
                            />
                            {!!index && (
                              <button
                                className="cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-center"
                                type="button"
                                onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                              >
                                <svg
                                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                  className="h-5 w-5"
                                  fill="none"
                                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                  stroke="currentColor"
                                >
                                  <path
                                    strokeLinecap="round"
                                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                                    strokeWidth={2}
                                    d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                                  />
                                </svg>
                              </button>
                            )}
                          </div>
                        );
                      })}

                    <span
                      className="cursor-pointer "
                      onClick={() => {
                        arrayHelpers.push({
                          itemName: "",
                          itemType: "",
                          itemQuantity: "",
                          itemRate: "",
                        });
                      }}
                    >
                      <span className="text-sm pt-3"> + Add Item</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                );
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="fixed mb-4 bottom-1 w-9/12">
            <div className="my-3 border-t border-gray-300"></div>
            <div className="flex justify-between">
              <div className="flex  ">
                <CustomInput
                  type="date"
                  name="purchasingDate"
                  placeholder="Purchaing Date"
                />
                <CustomInput
                  type="number"
                  name="subTotal"
                  placeholder="Sub Total"
                  disabled={true}
                  value={subTotal}
                />
                <CustomInput
                  name="discount"
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="Discount"
                />
                <CustomInput
                  type="number"
                  name="total"
                  placeholder="Total"
                  disabled={true}
                />
              </div>
              <div className=" flex justify-end items-center bg-white ">
                <SubmitButton
                  value="Add Booking"
                  name="addBooking"
                  onClick={hanldeSubmit}
                >
                  Add Purchase
                </SubmitButton>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    )}
  </Formik>
```

Here is CustomInput

```
const CustomInput = ({
type = INPUT_TYPES.TEXT_INPUT,
  label,
  name,
  placeholder = "",
  disabled,
  options = [],
  ...rest
}) => {
  const { values, errors, touched, handleChange } = useFormikContext();
  const value = _.get(values, name); // getting value if its a nested object
  let inputComponent = {
    [INPUT_TYPES.TEXT_INPUT]: (
      <TextInput
        value={value}
        label={label}
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={handleChange(name)}
        disabled={disabled}
        {...rest}
      />
    ),
    [INPUT_TYPES.NUMBER_INPUT]: (
      <NumberInput
        label={label}
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={handleChange(name)}
        disabled={disabled}
        {...rest}
      />
    ),
    [INPUT_TYPES.DATE_INPUT]: (
      <DateInput
        label={label}
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={handleChange(name)}
      />
    ),
    
    [INPUT_TYPES.SELECT]: (
      <Select
        placeholder={label}
        label={label}
        value={value}
        name={name}
        onChange={handleChange(name)}
        options={options}
      />
    ),
  }[type];
  return (
    <div>
      {inputComponent}
      <Error visible={touched[name]} error={_.get(errors, name)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

here are the initialValues and Schema

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
export const addPurchasesInitialValues = {
  items: [
    {
      itemName: "",
      itemType: "",
      itemQuantity: "",
      itemRate: "",
    },
  ],
  purchasingDate: "",
};

export const addPurchasesValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  items: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      itemName: Yup.string().required("Required"),
      itemType: Yup.string().required("Required"),
      itemQuantity: Yup.number().required("Required"),
      itemRate: Yup.number().required("Required"),
    })
  ),
  purchasingDate: Yup.string().required("Required"),
});
```